# MS Access 2013 Query Error

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have been working on some queries of MS Access 2013 but i am getting some errors, i applied this query but its says "Enter the parameter value" any help would be appreciated.

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Master List of PMA Membership Form]![SR#] & "*"
```

but it does not returns all the value, while pressing on search button from the Form Page and in my Excel table some values are empty some contains value. In earlier project i tried this query it worked fine, but in this case i don't know why its not working. I am Uploading a sample table data picture for reference.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean Access table (you have mentioned Excel table above)...I would suggest you to write the query on the designer view and run to check if it returns the correct data set (type the value rather than assigning form control value). Quite difficult to answer without looking at the database and the entire query. What does `select * from [Master List of PMA Membership Form] where [something] like "*yourvalue*"` returns?

Comment: well i need to figure out this problem i can send u the database if u want but please help me out with this matter. thx

Comment: I have read about two standards of JET SQL in access ANSI89 and ANSI92..in these two the wildcard behaves differently...you can attach the database and share the open link in dropbox..

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/amggh44o7i7ld29/Database3.accdb this is my database u can download it frm here and u can have a look

Comment: plz if u could give me any of ur social media adress or skype id so that we can have a deep conversation on this mess.. thx in advance

Comment: hubbak.khan@gmail.com & Facebook ID : hubbak , skype id : hubbak143